# How to test a delegate using Moq and NUnit

Tags: c#, delegates, tdd, moq, func

I have a factory class returning a delegate like below (GetDelegate method)

```
  public interface IFactory
{
    Func<int, string> GetDelegate(bool isValid);
}

public class AFactory : IFactory
{
    private readonly IService1 _service1;
    private readonly IService2 _service2;

    public AFactory(IService1 service1, IService2 service2)
    {
        _service1 = service1;
        _service2= service2;
    }

    public Func<int, string> GetDelegate(bool isValid)
    {
        if (isValid)
            return _service1.A;
        return _service2.B;
    }
}

public interface IService1
{
    string A(int id);
}

public interface IService2
{
    string B(int id);
}
```

I have been trying to write unit test for GetDelegate but dont know how to assert that a specific Func was returned depending on isValid

My attempt of a unit test is like below (which i am not happy with)

```
[Test]
    public void ShouldReturnCorrectMethod()
    {
        private var _sut = new AFactory(new Mock<IService1>(), new Mock<IService2>());

        var delegateObj = _sut.GetDelegate(true);
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(string), delegateObj.Method.ReturnType);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, delegateObj.Method.GetParameters().Count());
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to mock the result of calling `IService1.A` and `IService2.B`, in exactly the same way as if you were calling them directly. You could then check that when you call the returned delegate, you get the expected answer (and that the call was made to the appropriate service).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that should help. Out of curiosity, is this the "correct" use of a factory pattern? I am not really returning a class instance per se?

Comment: @nesh_s: Well you're returning a value... it doesn't need to be just a class. It's slightly unusual, but not particularly worrying.

Answer (score 1):

```
[Test]
public void GetDelegate_WhenCalledWithIsValidTrue_ReturnsDelegateA()
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<IService1> service1Mock = new Mock<IService1>();
    Mock<IService2> service2Mock = new Mock<IService2>();

    string expectedResultA = "A";
    string expectedResultB = "B";

    service1Mock.Setup(s => s.A(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(expectedResultA);
    service2Mock.Setup(s => s.B(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(expectedResultB);

    var _sut = new AFactory(service1Mock.Object, service2Mock.Object);

    // Act
    Func<int, string> delegateObj = _sut.GetDelegate(true);

    // Assert
    string result = delegateObj(0);
    Assert.AreEqual<string>(expectedResultA, result);
}
```